# error when creating table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a table in my `gym_system` database. Here is the code I'm using:

```
CREATE TABLE `Gym_System`.`login` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `password` CHAR(128) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 5

Can anyone see why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the last comma

```
CREATE TABLE `login` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `password` CHAR(128) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

[See fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c90321)